# How can one avoid being identified by facial recognition in a public setting?

Tags: anonymity, identity, biometrics, facial-recognition

Facial recognition is ubiquitous and methods like [disguises](https://gcn.com/articles/2017/09/07/facial-recognition-disguises.aspx), [surgical masks](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-55573802) and makeup are becoming ineffective owing to the improvement in algorithms.

In light of these advances, what are some countermeasures to avoid being identified in a public setting (cafe, restaurant, street etc)?

The purpose is to be able keep one's real identity a secret from someone who has access to a large database in which they have previously enrolled. Examples of such databases include photos scraped online from social media profiles and driver's license databases.

Comment: This would be a question better suited at WorldBuilding.

Comment: Do NOT delete and copy/paste a closed question. We asked questions that needed clarifying.

Comment: Ok, we're still not getting to the core point that we've been asking you about all along. A ***mask*** will defeat facial recognition. No tech will recognise you *if your face is covered*. So, I repeat my question, is your goal in this to defeat the technology ***while also*** not looking like you are trying to avoid detection? This point is ***crucial*** to being able to answer you with something relevant. I have often thought that a burn care mask would work perfectly, while avoiding questions about why one's face is covered. But is that even in scope?

Comment: @schroeder, to answer your question it would be preferred to have a solution where one can reasonably blend in.